# Redirecting with Slim PHP v 3.x

Tags: php, redirect, slim

I have one route in my Slim PHP application. It goes like this: gallery.dev/roomPicture/RoomDetails/212 for example. I would like to redirect all this requests to route gallery.dev/login. Here is what I tried:

```
$app->get('/roomPicture/RoomDetails/{id}', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args){
 //some code
 return $this->response->withStatus(200)->withHeader('Location', 'login');
```

This redirects me to gallery.dev/roomPicture/RoomDetails/login multiple times, and then it throws an error.

Do you have some idea how can I solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirection status code is 301. Also change url to absolute `/login`. Now it is relative to current path, so `login` is prepended to current path directory.

```
return $this->response->withStatus(301)->withHeader('Location', '/login');
```

or use special method for it `withRedirect($url, $status = null)`

```
return $this->response->withRedirect('/login');
```